# How to create complex dictionary in python with sum function?

Tags: python, dictionary

Basically, I have a file that looks like this:

```
year gender marst  age   people  
A    'abc'    x    12    1000
B    'tex'    y    34    120 
B    'tex'    x    78    1300
E    'yet'    x    88    1400
A    'abc'    y    22    150
A    'abc'    x    22    1600
```

I need to create a complex dictionary that looks like this:

```
complete_dict = {A:{'abc':{x:2600,y:150}}, 
                 B:{'tex':{x:1300,y:120}}, 
                 E:{'yet':{x:1400}}}
```

what I've tried was

```
import csv
import numpy as np

d={}

for row in reader:
    c=row['year']
    values = [row['age'], row['people']]
    s = row['gender']
    t = row['marst']
    if c not in d: 
        d[c]={}
    if s not in d[c]: 
        d[c][s] = {}    
    if t not in d[c][s]:
        d[c][s][t]= []
        d[c][s][t].append(values)
print d
```

So I could get the result

```
complete_dict = {A:{'abc':{x:[[12,1000],[22,1600]] ,y:[22,150]}}, 
                 B:{'tex':{x:[78,1300],y:[34,120]}}, 
                 E:{'yet':{x:[88,1400]}}}
```

I tried to use `append(sum(values))` instead of `append(values)`, but got an error.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i've add my try but the thing is I can get the complex dictionary with list all the values in an array but not the array's size in row. I tried use len(values).[0] but it return me with all the final value at the same size 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of the requirements, you don't need a list in your most nested dictionary. It looks like you want to count the number of appearances of different 'marst' entries. That means that you need to replace your last if with:

```
if t not in d[c][s]:
    d[c][s][t] = 1
else:
    d[c][s][t] += 1
```

Comment: thanks it works. Another question is if I want to return to a list of values in my first produced nested dictionary. What should I put cuz if I put the d.values() it returns to a wrong one

Comment: define "return to a list of values in my first produced nested dictionary". It doesn't make much sense

Comment: Hi what if I want to put the final value instead of the count? that is complete_dict = {A:{'abc':{x:2600,y:150}}, 
                 B:{'tex':{x:1300,y:120}}, 
                 E:{'yet':{x:1400}}}

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict


def factory():
    return defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int))

d = defaultdict(factory)

txt = """A    'abc'    x    12    0.001
B    'tex'    y    34    0.002  
B    'tex'    x    78    0.005
E    'yet'    x    88    0.090
A    'abc'    y    22    0.120
A    'abc'    x    22    0.120"""
for line in txt.splitlines():
    words = line.split()
    d[words[0]][words[1]][words[2]] += 1
```